# How to pass element ID variable to jQuery load function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am fairly new to Jquery and HTML so please bear with me. I have my index.html with a call to jquery-1.9.1.min.js and I want to create a script that would load an outside html file. Index.html is a fairly long file so I want to break up the section for cleaner code and make it easier to modify.

```
<html class="no-js">

<main>
<section id="testLoad"></section>
</main>

<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script>$("#testLoad").load("test.html #part-1"); </script>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see from the code above it loads the html file fine. What I want to do is set "#part-1" as a variable so that I can call the load script again but call a different ID from another part of the file.

I would also be open to different methods aside from this load function. All I need is to call an external html file (there are about 30 different sections) so it can display that sections data. If I do it this way is there a way to create a header file so that all of these section can have access to the same style sheet?

Answer (score 0):

You'd put your load function inside a named function and pass in an argument:

```
function loadStuff(divId) {
    $("#testLoad").load("test.html #" + divId + '');
}
```

In your event handler you'd call it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    loadStuff('someId');
});
```

You could also pass in the target ID in a similar manner.

As others have pointed out, this isn't the ideal way to do what's essentially client-side templating.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to be able to combine multiple different "partial" html files, and for this I would recommend you look into Angular which excels at exactly this.

Not sure why you are loading the JQuery js file the way you are. That really doesn't look safe.

Another thing you can do is create an "iffy" as some people call it where it is a script that is automatically called when the page is loaded.

```
<script>
  (function (){
    //code goes here
  }())
</script>
```

This code will run when that page is loaded.

Comment: I will take a look into using Angular. Thank you!

Comment: It is a LOT more complex than JQuery is but it is so much more powerful, and I enjoy coding it more.